# Можно ли сделать так, чтобы объект класса создавался только путём выделения памяти в куче, а не на стеке?

Tags: c++, классы

```
MyClass o; // error
MyClass * o = new MyClass; // ok
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Конечно, можно. Закройте его деструктор (сделайте его `private`).

Чтобы удалить выделенный динамически объект, вам придется написать отдельную функцию - например, друга или статический член - для удаления, вроде

```
friend void destroy(MyClass* t) { delete t; }

...
MyClass * o = new MyClass;

...
destroy(o);
```

Comment: Как такой объект потом освобождать? Метод с `delete this`?

Comment: См. дополненный ответ.

Comment: @maestro По возможности, используй умные указатели. @Harry А ведь можно пометить с помощью `delete` или ошибаюсь?;)

Comment: @sys_dev `= delete` деструктора не даст возможность удалить объект вовсе.

Comment: А почему не написать прямо внутри классса функцию 'void destroy() { delete this; } '  ?

Comment: @AlexTitov А чтоб выглядело более похоже на `delete` синтаксически. Может, и "вкусовщина", но мне так - `destroy(o)` нравится больше, чем `MyClass::destroy(o)` и тем более `o->destroy()`...

Comment: С помощью `placement new` объект всё ещё можно создать на стеке.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy И это будет ужасно :) Если вы будете удалять через `delete`, будет UB, если не будете - не будет вызываться деструктор, что тоже плохо. Словом, проблем будет много. Да и вопрос о размещении на стеке — это не о конкретной области памяти, а об автоматическом удалении...

Comment: Ужасно - не ужасно. Пока я не собрался его удалять, UB не наступил. Если читать вопрос буквально, нужно закрывать конструкторы. Деструктором не обойтись..

Answer (score 4):

Если в первую очередь имеет значение сам факт создания в куче, и нет  обязательного требования разрешать в клиентском коде запись вида `new MyClass`, то вместо сокрытия деструктора можно подойти с другой стороны жизненного цикла объекта и сделать приватным конструктор, предоставив соответствующую *create*-функцию или даже семейство функций:

```
class MyClass {
    MyClass();
public:  
    static MyClass* create() { return new MyClass; }
};
```

Теперь, чтобы не забыть сделать `delete` объекта в нужный момент и не получить утечку памяти, разумно возвращать не сырой указатель, а `std::unique_ptr`. Функция изменится так:

```
static std::unique_ptr<MyClass> create() { return std::unique_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass); }
```

Однако, если мы пойдём ещё дальше и заменим `std::unique_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass)` на `std::make_unique<MyClass>()` для уменьшения накладных расходов, то получим ошибку компиляции:

> ```
> error: calling a private constructor of class 'MyClass'
> ```

Возникает это из-за того, что мы пытаемся вызвать наш приватный конструктор по сути вне класса `MyClass`. Но это можно побороть следующим небольшим "хаком" - добавить приватный тип и использовать его в качестве дополнительного параметра для конструктора `MyClass`, при этом сам конструктор снова сделать публичным. Итоговый пример:

```
class MyClass {
    class tag {}; // скрытый от внешнего кода тип
public:
    MyClass(const tag&) {}      
    static std::unique_ptr<MyClass> create() { return std::make_unique<MyClass>(tag()); }
};

int main() {
    auto p = MyClass::create();
}
```